# Junit parametrize input and assertion

Tags: java, junit

I have similiar tests when only input/assertion value differ:

```
@Test
void test1() {
    // Given:
    val request = Request
            .builder()
            .totalAmount(new BigDecimal("160000"))
            .termInYears(20)
            .familySize(2)
            .incomeAmount(new BigDecimal("4000"))
            .costOfLiving(BigDecimal.ZERO)
            .build();

    // When:
    Result result =
            facade.getLoanAmount(request);

    // Then:
    result.getSimulations().forEach(simulation -> {
        if(simulation.getVariantCode().equals(Variant.A)) {
            assertThat(simulation.getInstallmentAmount().compareTo(new BigDecimal("720")) == 0);
            assertThat(simulation.getInterestRate().compareTo(new BigDecimal("0.0321")) == 0);
            assertThat(simulation.getLoanAmount().compareTo(new BigDecimal("127390")) == 0);
            assertThat(simulation.getNumberOfInstallmentsInMonths() == 240);
        } if(simulation.getVariantCode().equals(Variant.B)) {
            assertThat(simulation.getInstallmentAmount().compareTo(new BigDecimal("720")) == 0);
            assertThat(simulation.getInterestRate().compareTo(new BigDecimal("0.0321")) == 0);
            assertThat(simulation.getLoanAmount().compareTo(new BigDecimal("127390")) == 0);
            assertThat(simulation.getNumberOfInstallmentsInMonths() == 240);
        } if(simulation.getVariantCode().equals(Variant.C)) {
            assertThat(simulation.getInstallmentAmount().compareTo(new BigDecimal("720")) == 0);
            assertThat(simulation.getInterestRate().compareTo(new BigDecimal("0.0321")) == 0);
            assertThat(simulation.getLoanAmount().compareTo(new BigDecimal("127390")) == 0);
            assertThat(simulation.getNumberOfInstallmentsInMonths() == 240);
        }
    });
}

@Test
void test2() {
    // Given:
    val request = Request
            .builder()
            .totalAmount(new BigDecimal("200000"))
            .termInYears(20)
            .familySize(2)
            .incomeAmount(new BigDecimal("4000"))
            .costOfLiving(BigDecimal.ZERO)
            .build();

    // When:
    Result result =
            facade.getLoanAmount(request);

    // Then:
    result.getSimulations().forEach(simulation -> {
        if(simulation.getVariantCode().equals(Variant.A)) {
            assertThat(simulation.getInstallmentAmount().compareTo(new BigDecimal("720")) == 0);
            assertThat(simulation.getInterestRate().compareTo(new BigDecimal("0.0321")) == 0);
            assertThat(simulation.getLoanAmount().compareTo(new BigDecimal("127390")) == 0);
            assertThat(simulation.getNumberOfInstallmentsInMonths() == 240);
        } if(simulation.getVariantCode().equals(Variant.B)) {
            assertThat(simulation.getInstallmentAmount().compareTo(new BigDecimal("720")) == 0);
            assertThat(simulation.getInterestRate().compareTo(new BigDecimal("0.0321")) == 0);
            assertThat(simulation.getLoanAmount().compareTo(new BigDecimal("127390")) == 0);
            assertThat(simulation.getNumberOfInstallmentsInMonths() == 240);
        } if(simulation.getVariantCode().equals(Variant.C)) {
            assertThat(simulation.getInstallmentAmount() == null);
            assertThat(simulation.getInterestRate() == null);
            assertThat(simulation.getLoanAmount()== null);
            assertThat(simulation.getNumberOfInstallmentsInMonths() == 240);
        }
    });
}
```

This code works fine but I wonder how to write this code nicier. 
I know that there is `@ParameterizedTest` but i'm not sure this will reduce line of code in this scenario and how to provide input/output there? What would be best approach? I have to write many more of tests like that so I think providing input/output for many tests would be nice.
In Spock it would be a nice table but i have to use another tool.

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC. Mostly they are not constants, it's just an example. Only 0.0321 is constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using JUnit 5 (ParameterizedTests in 4 are very different, but would also make it possible), something like this should work:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("arguments")
void test(Request input, BigDecimal result) {
 // ...
}

public static Stream<Arguments> arguments() {
    r1 = Request.builder().build(); // add request configuration here
    r2 = Request.builder().build(); // ... and here
    return Stream.of(
       Arguments.of(r1, new BigDecimal("720")),
       Arguments.of(r2, null)
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this example. Can you provide more fit example? I mean that I provide `Request` as input not `BigDecimal` that i build with a builder. Also result is an `object` not a `BigDecimal` that can be build with a builder.

Comment: @tryingHard Well, what exactly is your result? Passing a Request in is trivial; I'll edit the answer to show it.

Comment: My result is `Result` class as posted in question. It contains up to 3 objects of type `Simulation` (`HashMap` collection) and you can check what simple types does one simulation contain by checking question (see assertions).

Comment: @tryingHard The Result object should still be created in your test method (using the parameterized Request). What the parameters should pass in are the fixture values you use in your asserts. From your examples, those are all BigDecimals (or nulls).

Comment: but the result values differ from input. If i want to parametrize this test i have to provide input and result. I want provide what values should be in `result` for specific `input`.

Comment: @tryingHard Exactly. What's keeping you from doing that? I thought the example should be pretty clear.

Comment: You should move creating `r1` and `r2` before return line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205580/discussion-between-ohlec-and-tryinghard).